# Почему Marshal.SizeOf возвращает 1 байт для переменной типа char?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, char, sizeof

Приведу код:

```
char charVal = '૧'; // код 0AE7
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(char)); // 2

Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(charVal)); // 1?
```

Здесь объявляем переменную типа `char` и пытаемся выяснить ее размер. Как видно, для размера типа результат будет 2, тогда как для переменной результат будет 1. Что-то находил по поводу того, что результат `Marshal.SizeOf(charVal)` зависит от установленного значения `CharSet`, но так и не понял, как управлять всем этим.

По идее, я указал в коде символ юникода, поэтому символ должен занимать 2 байта, но оказывается, что это не так. Почему?

Comment: Возможно вам это поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699005/why-is-char-4-bytes-in-marshal-sizeof

Comment: @alladuh прочитал. все равно не понял, почему `Marshal` себя так ведет.

Comment: _Marshal only relates to interop scenarios, passing data in/out of .NET. It doesn't tell you the size of things when they are inside .NET_ [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699005/why-is-char-4-bytes-in-marshal-sizeof#comment15515368_11699005)

Comment: Как я понимаю - `Marshal.SizeOf()` - создан для подсчета размера структур в unmanaged коде, для подсчета размера в managed коде - нужно использовать `sizeof()`

Comment: Вот тут при помощи атрибутов изменяют поведение: https://weblogs.asp.net/wim/217027

Comment: [sizeof() vs Marshal.SizeOf()](https://blog.tedd.no/2018/03/18/sizeof-vs-marshal-sizeof/)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо. Ответ оказался в одном предложении: _Managed data type Char (2 bytes) is identified as Windows type SBYTE (1 byte), and managed data type Boolean (1 byte) is identified as windows type BOOL (4 bytes)._

Comment: да, я подумал, что лучше ссылку на статью вставить, чем просто одно предложение скопипастить. Если вам стало всё ясно, напишите самоответ :)

Comment: @tym32167 не я же нашел ответ на вопрос, не буду же у вас забирать право на ответ)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Короткий ответ:** Потому что по-умолчанию (если не указана кодировка) символы маршалируются в ANSI. При этом кодировку можно установить с помощью [`[StructLayout]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset?view=netframework-4.8) и [`[DllImport]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netframework-4.8) ([Default Marshaling for Characters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/6tyybbf2(v=vs.71))):

> When a managed Char type, which has Unicode formatting by default, is passed to unmanaged code, the interop marshaler converts the character set to ANSI. You can apply the [DllImportAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute to platform invoke declarations and the [StructLayoutAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset?view=netframework-4.8) attribute to a COM interop declaration to control which character set a marshaled Char type uses.

Использовать `Marshal.SizeOf` имеет смысл только при взаимодействии с неуправляемым кодом. Результат для `char` мало что означает.

**Длинный ответ:**

Вроде выковырял описание этого поведения из документации.

В документации [`Marshal.SizeOf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf_System_Object_) говорится, что для символов результат определяется установленным `CharSet`:

> ... For character types, the size is affected by the [`CharSet`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset?view=netframework-4.8) value applied to that class. ...

Что это означает? Это означает, что если тип `char` используется в структуре, то размер, который для символа вернет `SizeOf` определяется свойством `CharSet` атрибута [`StructLayout`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset?view=netframework-4.8):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct OneByte
{
    public char ch; //1
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct TwoByte
{
    public char ch; //2
}
```

Теперь осталось выяснить какая проставлена кодировка для структуры [`System.Char`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). В документации использованный атрибут явно не указан, но указывается, что по умолчанию используется ANSI:

> Char values and interop
> When a managed Char type, which is represented as a Unicode UTF-16 encoded code unit, is passed to unmanaged code, the interop marshaler **converts the character set to ANSI by default.** You can apply the [DllImportAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute to platform invoke declarations and the [StructLayoutAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset?view=netframework-4.8) attribute to a COM interop declaration to control which character set a marshaled Char type uses.

Для верности проверяем [исходный код `Char`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,02f2b1a33b09362d):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct Char
```

Как видим [`CharSet`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset?view=netframework-4.8) не задан, соответственно, он принимает значение по умолчанию. В документации указывается `LPSTR` (однобайтный тип):

> Indicates whether string data fields within the class should be marshaled as LPWSTR or LPSTR by default.

Но опять для верности проверяем [код `StructLayoutAttribute`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/attributes.cs,889) и выясняем что по умолчанию используется `CharSet.None`:

```
CharSet charSet = CharSet.None;
switch (type.Attributes & TypeAttributes.StringFormatMask)
{
   ...
```

Который, согласно документации, устарел и эквивалентен `Ansi`.

`Marshal.SizeOf` скорее всего просто проверяет значение кодировки в атрибуте и возвращает на его основании 1. Этот результат имеет мало смысла т.к. `Char` не будет маршалится как отдельная структура В практических сценариях маршалинга будет использоваться кодировка, заданная для конкретной структуры.

В процессе поиска нашел актуальную цитату из старой книги [.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232170X) Адама Натана:

> **Caution**
>
> Never use `Marshal.SizeOf` to determine the "real size" of a managed type, because the results can be misleading. Just think of `Marshal.SizeOf` as `Marshal.UnmanagedSizeOf`. An appropriate use of `Marshal.SizeOf` is to fill a struct's "size field" when passing it to unmanaged code. ...
>
> Furthermore, you should never use `Marshal.SizeOf` with the `System.Char` type to determine the current platform's character size — use [`Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.systemdefaultcharsize?view=netframework-4.8) instead. **This is because `Marshal.SizeOf` always reports 1 for the size of the `System.Char` type regardless of platform due to an extremely subtle reason. It reports the size of the `System.Char` value type in the `mscorlib` assembly, which has a single character field. Because the definition is marked with `CharSet.Ansi`, the structure would have a size of 1 byte if marshalled to unmanaged code as a plain struct.** ... But because the `System.Char` type is treated specially as a character primitive type, it is never passed as a plain struct to unmanaged code. By default, character parameters and return types are marshalled as 2-byte Unicode characters, and character fields in a structure are marshalled depending on the structure's character set. Note that doing `sizeof(char)` in C# unsafe code always returns 2 regardless of platform because .Net characters are always Unicode.

Не уверен насчет маршалинга параметров и возвращаемых значений, но остальная информация вроде бы не устарела.

Comment: ну за такой ответ, вы просто не оставляете выбора, однозначно плюс )

Comment: @tym32167 Благодарю)